# How to set title only for index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

First of all, I would like to tell you guys that I am beginner and I started develop project. While developing this project I am planning to learn.

My question is how to set title only for index page? For now, I customize my title according to page in this way:

**This is layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is helper**

```
  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = 'Site Name Here'
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{page_title} | #{base_title}"
    end
  end
```

And I call this in every page. Of course according to page About Us changes.

```
<% provide(:title, 'About Us') %>
```

So when I visit about page the title is About Us | Site Name Here
or when I visit faq page the title is Frequently Asked Questions | Site Name Here

and according to my helper, if I don't provide title in index page, the helper fill set the title as "Site Name". So, everything works perfect. But what I wanna do is to change index's title. I want to add Welcome to my site for example. If I provide it in :title, the title is gonna be like "welcome to my site | site name". So I don't want "| site name" there.

I hope I explained well my question. Thank you for your help. If it was PHP, I could just check which page I am on in the helper, if it is index, I could echo what title I want but I don't know how to do it in rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try utilizing `controller_name` and `action_name` as a condition to target the index action of the controller in question. Using and `elsif` statement you return just the `page_title` without `base_title`:

```
# Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = 'Site Name Here'
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    elsif controller_name == 'hello' && action_name == 'index'
      "#{page_title}"
    else
      "#{page_title} | #{base_title}"
    end
  end
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Great answer. I actually didn't know that I could write controller_name in a if statement. I learned something. Thanks.

Comment: You could also utilize the controller_name and action_name in your ERB templates as necessary as well. This can be helpful for conditional display logic. Happy coding!